# my wp-login page doesn't load

Tags: login

Suddenly, my website stopped loading on all kind of devices. When I tried to login my wp admin as well as control panel,the login pages for both are also not loading. The error shown "the site can't be reached". Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, a few questions : 1- Is the error generated by chrome or it's a debug error by php/wordpress? 2- Can you access your site using ftp? 3- Only admin panel is having problem or the entire website?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there are not hosting issues (like you can't get to the public area of the site), it may be that a plugin is causing problems.

Best way I have used to find an offending plugin is to use your cPanel File Manager access (or FTP, or whatever) to rename the 'plugins' folder (in the 'wp-content' folder). Then try to log in.

If that works, then create a new plugins folder and move several plugins from the renamed folder to the plugin folder. Repeat and fine-tune until you find the offending plugin.

Similarly, you could rename several subfolders in the 'plugin' folder (starting with the most recently installed; via checking the plugin's sub-folder timestamp) and see if a recently installed plugin is causing the problem.

Of course, this will affect your public-facing site, as plugins will be temporarily disabled, so you may have to do it during a low-useage time on your site. But that procedure has worked well for me.

Comment: Renaming plugin directories can be so tedious. I prefer a simple sql script to disable all plugins: `UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';`

Comment: Well, you could do that, but that would only tell you that a plugin was causing problems. You don't know *which* plugin is the problem.

A rename of the plugin folder will tell you right away if *any* plugin is the problem. If problem persists, you can look elsewhere. If problem is solved, then adding back a couple of plugins at a time will tell you which plugin is the problem. That process should take less than 15 minutes for most site - about a minute for each plugin rename is all it takes to see if the login will start working again.